# Could I bring my furry dog plushie into Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia

I'm planning to go to Sydney this month by plane, and I have a furry dog plushie that I'd like to bring with me as well. May I know whether or not I should declare my dog plushie toy when I enter Australia?

Comment: What is your toy filled with? (In the past that would have been natural fibers which were not allowed but these days there are many more options.)

Comment: That is two questions. "Should I declare?" and "Can I bring?". I have declared all kinds of things in Australia and been told I can bring them. But it was still correct to declare them. Can you explain why you think the toy might not be allowed? Is it made of animal products such as real dog fur?

Comment: It is made of polyester..

Comment: Do you plan to leave it in Australia as a gift for someone?  Is it particularly valuable?

Answer (score 7):

If it’s just a toy containing no food, plant material or animal items, and it doesn’t fall into any of the other banned goods categories, for example a fake designer product, then you don’t need to declare it. If you have any doubt, declare it.
Source: [Can you bring it in?](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/can-you-bring-it-in/declare-it)